# Selecting from view changes order of rows compared to selecting from view's script

Tags: postgresql, select, view, sql-order-by

I made a view in PostgreSQL and I've run into an issue when selecting from a certain view.
The order of the rows has a lot of meaning, and when I select using the view the order is changed compared to when I'm just running the script myself.

PS: I join a few tables using a column that determines the order of the rows.
Meaning I select table1.order_index and join another table on that table's order_index column.

What's the explanation for something like that?
Thanks.

Comment: If you don't use an `order by` there is no guaranteed sort order. If you need a _guaranteed_ sort order the only way to do that is to use an `order by` (but please do **not** include the `order by` in the view definition, use when when you select _from_ the view)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've edited the question, thanks for reminding me of that.